# Sort lines by unicode value

Tags: sort, unicode

I'm trying to sort a text file linewise by their Unicode values. As far as I can tell, this means numerals first, then letters, then CJK-Ideographs. However, `sort` (with `LC_ALL=C`) fails horribly at this task. Here is an excerpt from my list:

```
[#ゆうかりんちゃんねる]
[チ→ム♂ツナギ]
[ぞめ]
...
[サディスティックブラウニー]
[ほねとかわとがはなれるおと]
[10th Avenue Cafe]
[2nd Flush]
...
[Alstroemeria Records & Cradle]
[ALTERNATIVE]
[アルトノイラント - Altneuland]
[Amateras Records]
[セブンスヘブンAmmy's]
[anagram]
[Analyze]
...
[Z.S.G TRAXXX]
[α music]
[Яiselied]
[一人華飯スペシャル]
[七瀬屋]
```

It seems like `sort` ignores (at least sometimes) the characters it can't read, because `Altneuland` would indeed be between `Alternative` and `Amateras Records`. Someone suggested using `msort`, but it failed as well (with options `-u c`, `-u d`, and `-u n`, respectively).

First, why is it acting so unexpected?
Second, how can I fix this?

Add:// I'm using Raspbian on a Raspberry Pi (B)

Comment: sorting is always dependent on locale.

Comment: `LC_ALL=C` is for ASCII/7-bit, it's pretty much guaranteed to do the wrong thing for multi-byte characters. Which unicode encoding? (UTF-8, UTF-16, UTF-32, legacy UCS-x?). GNU sort with a correctly set locale is almost certainly up to the task.

Comment: @mr.spuratic, at least all of those encodings are meant to sort the same when regarded as their byte value and sorting by byte value which the C locale is meant to do. locales other than C and POSIX don't sort by byte value but follow language specific rules.

Comment: @StephaneChazelas yes, of course, but I mean specifically the input file encoding, how can UTF-16 or UTF-32 sort "correctly" if the endianness is not specified?

Comment: Oh yes, you're right, I forgot about the endianness issue, not to mention the fact that utf16/ucs2 newline characters will be on two bytes, so the content would be mangled by `LC_ALL=C sort`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What system are you using?

```
LC_ALL=C sort < your-file.txt
```

Where `your-file.txt` is the text you posted in utf-8 encoding, sorts as:

```
[#ゆうかりんちゃんねる]
[10th Avenue Cafe]
[2nd Flush]
[ALTERNATIVE]
[Alstroemeria Records & Cradle]
[Amateras Records]
[Analyze]
[Z.S.G TRAXXX]
[anagram]
[α music]
[Яiselied]
[ぞめ]
[ほねとかわとがはなれるおと]
[アルトノイラント - Altneuland]
[サディスティックブラウニー]
[セブンスヘブンAmmy's]
[チ→ム♂ツナギ]
[一人華飯スペシャル]
[七瀬屋]
```

On my system (sort from GNU coreutils 8.13, Debian EGLIBC 2.13-38). Which when piped to `cut -c2 | tr -d \\n | recode ..dump` gives:

```
UCS2   Mne   Description

0023   Nb    number sign
0031   1     digit one
0032   2     digit two
0041   A     latin capital letter a
0041   A     latin capital letter a
0041   A     latin capital letter a
0041   A     latin capital letter a
005A   Z     latin capital letter z
0061   a     latin small letter a
03B1   a*    greek small letter alpha
042F   JA    cyrillic capital letter ya
305E   zo    hiragana letter zo
307B   ho    hiragana letter ho
30A2   A6    katakana letter a
30B5   Sa    katakana letter sa
30BB   Se    katakana letter se
30C1   Ti    katakana letter ti
4E00
4E03
```

Same on an older system with `sort` from GNU coreutils 7.4, EGLIBC 2.11.1-0ubuntu7.12

Comment: I'm using a Raspberry Pi. I'll later try and see what your command results in

Comment: No, on Ubuntu with sort 8.12 I get the exact same result as on my Raspberry Pi

Answer (score 3):

The question has been solved. Appearently `LC_ALL=C` is not enough. I need to write `export LC_ALL=C` in order to be recognized by `sort`. This is my bad, but should be noted for future unicode-sorters

Comment: Well, yes `var=value` sets a **shell** variable, so is not going to affect any other command unless that shell variable is marked for exporting.

Comment: No, you should not. You just need to add LC_ALL=C before sort command.

Comment: Compare `echo   | tr ' ' '\n' | sort`

Comment: .. with `echo   | tr ' ' '\n' | LC_ALL=C sort`

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment. This question was asked by me 5 and a half years ago and in the meantime I have learned *a lot* more about how shells work.